# Exits don't insert else insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have started to learn asp.net. I am using VS 2013 Express for C#.
How to make that a some if case to check a duplicate value and if this value is exists then I get a red summary about it and can't insert to DB else insert to database and too with update button.

Can you help?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TSS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");

protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vardas = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtname") as TextBox;
    var pavarde = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlastname") as TextBox;
    var pozymis = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "insert into asmenys (name,lastname, status) values(@name,@lastname, @status)";
    comm.Connection = con;

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status![enter image description here][1].Text);

    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    DataBind();
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

When you say check if a value exists, what fields should not have duplicates? Those are the fields you have to write a select statement for to check if they exist first.

Example

```
protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vardas = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtname") as TextBox;
    var pavarde = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlastname") as TextBox;
    var pozymis = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    comm.CommandText = "select lastname from asmenys where lastname = @lastname";
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Values exist");
    }
    else
    {
        comm.CommandText = "insert into asmenys (name,lastname, status) values(@name,@lastname, @status)";
        comm.Connection = con;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status![enter image description here][1].Text);

        con.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        DataBind();
    }
}
```